# Reading doc with nested dictionary inside array and returning value

Tags: python

This is my .txt file

```
{'word1': {'doc1': 2}}
{'word2': {'doc2': 5}}
{'word3': {'doc3': 4}}
{'word4': {'doc4': 2}}
{'word5': {'doc5': 1}}
```

The .txt file means: { word : {doc in which word appears : position on that doc} }

What I want to do is to read the text file and give me the position of a specific word on that doc.
An example of what I was trying to do:

```
def search(word, doc):
    with open('extras/file.txt', 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if word and doc in line:
               print(word, "|", doc, "|", line)
    
search("word2", "doc2")
```

In this example I want the retrieve the "5", but I don't know on how to access the position.
Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

def search(word, doc):
    with open('extras/docPositions.txt', 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            d = ast.literal_eval(line)
            if word in d and doc in d[word]:
               print(f"{word} is in {doc} at line {d[word][doc]}")

>>> search("word2", "doc2")
word2 is in doc2 at line 5
```